# Extending Context List module to show names of blocks/nodes

Tags: drupal

I did do a search on this, but found nothing and it is a custom module. It is called `Context List` Named and extends the `Context List` module so that the blocks will show titles instead of node or block number. The project maintainer created two hooks for me, but I have not been able to figure out how to get it working. Here is my function:

```
function context_list_named_context_list_reaction_block_name(&$block_name, &$details) {
    if(preg_match('/^nodeblock:(\d+)$/', $block_name)) {
      $block = block_load('nodeblock',$details->delta);
      $block_name = $block->subject;
      //$block_name = ;
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/^block:(\d+)$/', $block_name)) {
      $block = block_load('block',$details->delta);
      $block_name = $block->subject;
      //return $block_name;
    }
    $block_name = 'test';   
}
```

So you can see that I am just trying to set `$block_name = 'test';` just to get started, but I am not seeing anything change on the `Context List page`. (Context block info module offers the same type of list with just the `node/block` numbers as well.)